# Simulating Safari 6 on OS X 10.9

Tags: cross-browser, safari6

Is there a feasible way to simulate Safari 6 on OS X 10.9?

I haven't been able to find a way myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a virtual machine (using [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) running OS X Lion or Mountain Lion, then you can install Safari 6.1 from the App Store, or using the following links:

- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/18/32/041-6651/147ugedbeiqpz43czixlgawayfoa7tjyjv/Safari6.1MountainLion.pkg
- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/47/40/041-6648/a9y00qwi8esz3gl5v2gfik1p3rgvn7zftz/Safari6.1Lion.pkg

Comment: Broken links in post